# super key not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I have recently upgraded my os from `ubuntu 12.04 (32bit)` to `ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit)`. But after upgrading, the `super` key is not working. How can I remap the key?

Comment: go grab the unity tweak tool from the app store. It lets you change key mapping and it has one for the super key I can see from mine.

Comment: Installed `Tweak tool`. But can not find the option where I can remap key shortcuts.

Comment: did you fix this? I have the same issue.

Comment: What does not working mean? You get nothing when you press the key? Or, don't you see shortcuts when you hold the super key down? Try disabling work spaces. My superkey with ubuntu 14.04 doesn't display shortcuts when work spaces are enabled. Try increasing resolution if you can.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

Does the shortcut show up here?

[image]

Maybe try hitting reset to default to see if that fixes it.

you could also try and add a custom shortcut for this. I'm trying to find out that the command would be for this so I'm going to do some research on it.

[image]

Comment: Could not solve. May be There is some other issue. Thanks anyway for help.